# MailChimp API V3 Dynamic content

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am investigating the possibilities of MailChimp for mailings. One of the requirements we are looking for is to add dynamic content to a campaign.

According to some SO questions

- [Looking to give MailChimp dynamic content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26583669/looking-to-give-mailchimp-dynamic-content)
- [Mailchimp API not replacing mc:edit content sections (using ruby library)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29366766/mailchimp-api-not-replacing-mcedit-content-sections-using-ruby-library)

this should be possible in V2 of the API. In their own documentation https://templates.mailchimp.com/getting-started/template-language/ MailChimps describes the possibilities for dynamic content.

However, I am unable to see how to edit a mc:edit element using the current V3 API.

The Playground page on their site doesn't reveal any clues either.

Does anyone has experience with this matter?

Thank you!

Comment: I hope this question is going to be answered. I see the possibilitiy of abuse of MailChimp where Mandrill should be used, but also I see a szenario where dynamic content in MailChimp is required and useful.

Comment: @JakobAlexanderEichler, hey guys, I just wrote the detailed overview on how to [add dynamic content via editable area & API 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53096852/6597265), and [replace entire MailChimp mail with custom HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53086909/6597265).