# Sendgrid API v3 Send a campaign with a template and dynamic template data

Tags: node.js, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3, sendgrid-templates

I'm using Sendgrid's new API (v3) with Node js + libraries `@sendgrid/mail` and `@sendgrid/client`.

**What I want to achieve**: send a weekly digest to all my contacts (except those who unsubscribe from this group). I use a template I created via Sendgrid thanks to its template_id, as well as dynamic template data to populate the mail with the weekly data.

**Problem**:

- I can send a marketing campaign using [/v3/marketing/singlesends](https://sendgrid.api-docs.io/v3.0/single-sends/update-single-send) to all my contacts with my template but I can't send it with my dynamic template data.
- I can send one email at a time with my template + dynamic template data but for this I need to retrieve all my contacts first and I can only retrieve the last 50 contacts from this endpoint [/v3/marketing/contacts](https://sendgrid.api-docs.io/v3.0/contacts/get-all-contacts) (they disabled the pagination). I may have been able to retrieve them all from this endpoint [/contactdb/recipients](https://sendgrid.api-docs.io/v3.0/contacts-api-recipients/retrieve-recipients), the problem is I created my Sendgrid account after they released their new API so I can't access it.

Any idea on how to perform this?

**Current code:**

1) Configure campaign

```
const sgClient = require('@sendgrid/client')
var params={
    'name': 'Weekly Digest #'+nb,
    'sender_id': sg_sender_id,
    'suppression_group_id': sg_unsub_group_id,
    'template_id': id_template,
    'dynamicTemplateData': template_params,
    //also tried with 'dynamic_template_data' instead, not working
    'filter': {'send_to_all': true}
}

let url='/v3/marketing/singlesends/' + campaign_id.toString('base64')
const request = {
    method: 'PATCH',
    url: url,
    body: params
}
sgClient.setApiKey(config.sendgrid_key)
sgClient.request(request)
.then(([response, body]) => {
    console.log('body:', body)
})
.catch(error => {
    console.error('error:', error.toString())
})
```

2) Send campaign

```
let url='/v3/marketing/singlesends/' + campaign_id.toString('base64') + '/schedule'
let params={'send_at': 'now'}
const request = {
    method: 'PUT',
    url: url,
    body: params
}
sgClient.setApiKey(config.sendgrid)
sgClient.request(request)
.then(([response, body]) => {
    console.log('body:', body)
})
.catch(error => {
    console.error('error:', error.toString())
})
```

Comment: Did you figure out a solution to this problem? I am facing the same limitations of their API like you...

Comment: Unfortunately no. I grab my contacts from MailChimp and send a dynamic template with Sendgrid to each one of them.

Comment: I actually also switched to Mailchimp and found a solution there. Their API seems also better. If you want I can share my code with you? I basically create a campaign and then update the content with a custom html + inject data dynamically. In my case a table.

Comment: Yes, sure! For now I stay on Sendgrid because it's less expensive. But I might change some day.

Answer (score 0):

**I found a solution to the problem with Mailchimp**, hence this will now answer the issue exactly. **As of Sept 2020, it's not possible to achieve this via the SendGrid API** but you can do potentially something similar like I did. My answer is based on this post here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53096852/4163583

1. Sign up and create a Mailchimp account
2. Create an Audience who should receive your emails (they will call this later list in their API docs FYI)
3. Go to Campaigns -> Email Templates and create a new Template with "Paste in code"

[image]

4. Inside your editor for the template, you can now add some parts with Mailchimp's own language here. Compare my screenshot, but they have a [guide](https://mailchimp.com/help/create-editable-content-areas-with-mailchimps-template-language/) here that explains it further.

[image]

My goal was to have certain parts designed in the editor and certain areas that I want to fill with dynamic content via the API. Hence I had a few lines at different locations where I will add dynamic code.

5. Now we can actually write code. What I am doing is basically the following:
   First load the data from the DB, then bring it in the right formal and create HTML code that I will inject into the Mailchimp template at the right place, then create + update the campaign with the dynamic content and send it out. Let's go:

```js
export const sendOutDailyDigest = async () => {
  const campaignDetails = {
    // Details about your campagin e.g. subject or sender
  };
  try {
    // I'm retrieving here my data from the DB
    const data: any = await retrieveDataForDailyDigest();
    // This is the data that I want to inject in the template
    const dynamicData = {
      producthunt: fillProducthuntProductTable(data.producthunt),
      betalist: fillBetalistProductTable(data.betalist),
      crunchbase: fillCrunchbaseTable(data.crunchbase),
      yesterdayDate: `Yesterday's Highlights`,
    };
    // Sending out the campaign
    await sendOutMailchimpCampaign(
      campaignDetails,
      MAILCHIMP_LIST,
      MC_SEGMENT_DAILY_DIGEST,
      DAILY_DIGEST_TEMPLATE_ID,
      dynamicData
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error during sendOutDailyDigest ", error);
  }
};
```

6. To create the HTML that will be later injected I have for example a function lik this here:

```js
export const fillProducthuntProductTable = (products: any) => {
  let tablebody = "";
  products.forEach((p: any) => {
    const productRow = `
          <tr>
              <td><a href="${p.url}" alt="">${p.title}</a></td>
              <td>${p.description}</td>
              <td>${p.category}</td>
              <td>${p.upvotes}</td>
          </tr>
          `;
    tablebody += productRow;
  });
  return `
        <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <th>Startup Name</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Upvotes</th>
            </tr>
            ${tablebody}
        </table>`;
};
```

7. Let's look what I'm doing in `sendOutMailchimpCampaign`. The important calls are the [create campaign](https://mailchimp.com/developer/api/marketing/campaigns/add-campaign/), [update campaign content](https://mailchimp.com/developer/api/marketing/campaign-content/set-campaign-content/), and [send out campaign](https://mailchimp.com/developer/api/marketing/campaigns/send-campaign/).

```js
const sendOutMailchimpCampaign = async (
  campaignDetails: any,
  mailchimpList: string,
  mailchimpSegment: number,
  templateId: number,
  dynamicData: any
) => {
  try {
    // Creating a campaign
    const campaign: any = await createMailchimpCampaign(
      mailchimpList,
      mailchimpSegment,
      campaignDetails
    );
    // Updating the campaign with the dynamic data that I fetched from the db
    await updateCampaignContent(campaign.id, templateId, dynamicData);

    // Sending out the campaign
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      mailchimp.campaigns
        .send(campaign.id)
        .then((_: any) => {
          console.log("Successfully sent out daily digest.");
          resolve();
        })
        .catch((error: any) => {
          console.log("Error sending out daily digest: ", error);
          reject();
        });
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error during sendOutMailchimpCampaign ", error);
  }
};

// Function for creating the above mentioned campaign like this: 

export const createMailchimpCampaign = (
  mailchimpList: string,
  mailchimpSegment: number,
  campaignDetails: any
) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    mailchimp.campaigns
      .create({
        type: "regular",
        recipients: {
          list_id: mailchimpList,
          segment_opts: {
            saved_segment_id: mailchimpSegment,
          },
        },
        settings: campaignDetails,
      })
      .then((response: any) => {
        resolve(response);
      })
      .catch((error: any) => {
        console.log(error);
        reject(error);
      });
  });
};

// Function for updating the campaign with the dynamic content

const updateCampaignContent = async (
  campaignId: number,
  templateId: number,
  dynamicData: any
) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    mailchimp.campaigns
      .setContent(campaignId, {
        template: {
          id: templateId,
          sections: dynamicData,
        },
      })
      .then((_: any) => {
        resolve();
      })
      .catch((error: any) => {
        console.log(error);
        reject(error);
      });
  });
};
```

That's it. The code is in TypeScript, hence I apologize or all Javascript friends here but I guess you can translate it. I hope this helps someone and saves them some hours, even though it's not the solution in SendGrid.