# Mailchimp Dynamic Content: add customized link in subscribe email

Tags: mailchimp, mandrill, mailchimp-api-v3.0

We want to start a service with Mailchimp where every subscriber will get a customized link in the email she receives. The Subscription Form will be on a wordpress website (not my decision).

There is a pool of thousand of links with a unique parameter, which we have stored on our webserver, like these examples

- https://example.com/link?code=a25b1d085f3aec4b256
- https://example.com/link?code=32219abb336de28a103
- etc
  Every code parameter should only be used once and should be kept as secret as possible. So I don't think it is a good idea to send the code from the form to mailchimp in a hidden field.

I don't know, if this is possible. Is Mailchimp even the right tool to do this?
I'm not sure, where to start the journey.

I don't think webhooks will help me here, as those are only one-way communication without a backwards channel, as far as I understand.

I checked the Mailchimp API documentation, but I might be too foolish to understand, which of the multiple options I need to use.

I found this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53096852/476951, but I don't know, if this will suit my needs. As I understand it, this will chhange the mail template in Mailchimp UI with an API request and store it. The successive emails will all use this changed template until I change the template again. This seems not to be the correct way.

So, here are the two workflows that might be possible, but I don't know if they are.

1. Have a form created in Wordpress (not the embedded Mailchimp form), and create a custom form handler with admin-post.php like described [here](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/handling-form-submissions/). Then use the API to send the email through the Mailchimp service with my dynamic link in it. But how. Every tuorial I found sends campaigns via the API, not individual mails to single recepients
2. Somehow manage Mailchimp to get the dynamic content via some sort of webhooks or the likes.

Is any of these workflows suitable to do this?
If yes, who should I set these up?
Is there anything else I might have missed?

## Edit

Or do I need to use Mailchimp Transactional Email service (former called Mandrill)?

Comment: See here: https://mailchimp.com/help/create-unique-urls-for-subscribers/